# how do I stack express and react app together and then run it in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, docker, dockerfile

I have searched around without much luck, or maybe because I'm too noob, but I this project online on github, https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_express_starter, and I have tried to make it so it can run with docker, but it doesn't seem like it don't want to work, in the docker terminal it says that the server is started and the react app at localhost:3000 but nothing shows up when I paste it into the browser, not even the server and api is accessable, so I figured it has to be something with the docker file.I place the dockerfile in the project folder.

My dockerfile says

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD npm run client-install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run dev
```

and I build it by "docker build -t project ." and then run it with "docker run -p 5000:5000 project"

thank you in advance

[screenshot of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuxnf.jpg)

EDIT: OK, I have made the server working, it turns out that docker machine has another ip than localhost, so port 5000 work as well as api call, but the react part doesn't show up on port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mising EXPOSE as apart of your dockerfile. This can be done right before

`CMD npm run dev`

like so

`EXPOSE 3000`

Comment: it didnt work unfortunately you can see the image I uploaded for further info

Comment: @AnhVũMai can you try running `docker run -p 5000 -d 3000 exam`? The -p flag is for the external port you would like to connect to, and -d is the destination (internal) port that express is running on.

Comment: i get an error message "Unable to find image '3000:latest' locally", I should also mention that I use docker toolbox by the way, if that can be any help. Tried it with 5000 and got the same message

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was able to figure it out thanks to it, I just had to open 2 ports when I run and use the docker machine ip instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The internal port is 3000 - you need to make that available externally (on the host machine).  Move `EXPOSE 3000` before the `CMD`, then `docker run -p 5000:3000 project` should make your docker container available as `localhost:5000/`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was able to figure it out thanks to it, I just had to open 2 ports when I run and use the docker machine ip instead of localhost.